# parse html code from json using native javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, jsonp

Is it possible to get out the code that is inside a json file? You can have a look at it here: http://www.bryzgalov.directadvert.ru/show.cgi?adp=768&json=4
What is the code or method should I use to put the html code inside any raw div?
I tried to use jsonp, but there is a mistake:

> unexpected token <

```
<script>
    function myFunction(data){              
        var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        document.getElementById('advBlock').innerHTML = arr;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bryzgalov.directadvert.ru/show.cgi?adp=768&json=4&callback=myFunction"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONP` data is already a Javascript object, not a JSON string, so you don't need to parse it:

```html
<div id="advBlock"></div>
<script>
  function myFunction(data) {
    document.getElementById('advBlock').innerHTML = data;
  }
</script>
<script src="http://www.bryzgalov.directadvert.ru/show.cgi?adp=768&json=4&callback=myFunction"></script>
```

Comment: @venom Then the element with ID `advBlock` does not exist in the document.

Comment: @DrewGaynor have a look at this: http://cheil.nichost.ru/email/newsearch/ i thought there is no data to be added to block... not the block

Comment: @Buzinas now i got the problem, there is a problem with orders :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="advBlock"></div>
<script src="http://www.bryzgalov.directadvert.ru/show.cgi?adp=768&json=4&callback=myFunction"></script>
 <script> function myFunction(data) { document.getElementById('advBlock').innerHTML = data; } </script>
```

You have to add the script before your function call.

Comment: Wrong, if you do that, the script will try to call the `myFunction` function before it's declared. You can only add the script before, if you put the attribute `async`, then the function will be declared before the callback. But it's simpler to just declare the function before.

Comment: Wait,  no that's wrong. Can't figure out how to delete on movie